# Why is type arrayp[] the same as type* arrayp as parameter of a function?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference

Why is f.e. `int arrayp[]` the same as `int* arrayp`, as parameter in the definition/declaration of a function?

```
 int* foo(int arrayp[]){}
```

A pointer to the first element of an `int` array passed as argument in the caller.

Like:

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 int* foo (int arrayp[]);

 int main(void)
 {
    int a[] = { 10,5,4,2,1 };
    int *p;

    p = foo(a);

    printf("%d",*p);

    return 0;
 }

 int* foo(int arrayp[])
 {
     *arrayp = 0;
     return arrayp;          
 }
```

---

Why is `int arrayp[]` a pointer to the first element of an array of type `int`? IMHO I think this is very confusing. Some people may think that they passing an entired array (pass by value) with this expression.

Comment: What do you expect in response to "why?", short of "Because that's what the language specification states"? There's nothing really to discuss. You demonstrate that you already understand it's _not_ pass-by-value, so are you really trying to ask "How do I pass an array by value"?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts There certainly are answers to "why". They just aren't to be found in the C Standard.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts: Of course there are reasons and there are things to discuss. When C was first being developed, an array was a big thing, even if it was just a few elements, and it would have been unwieldy to pass it by value (would use up too much stack and/or register space) or by transparent reference (arranging for the compiler to make a copy, if needed, and pass that by reference hidden from the programmer). At the time, the easy and obvious solution was to pass arrays by address, and, for the ease of the programmer, to provide automatic conversions and adjustments for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In function parameter types, arrays are implicitly adjusted to the pointer they would decay to.

Thus, these function declaration pairs, for example, are compatible:

```
void foo(int a[]);
void foo(int *a);  //compatible declaration

void bar(int a[][2][3]);
void bar(int (*a)[2][3]);  //compatible declaration
```

Dennis Ritchie (the language author) explains this confusing rule in https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/chist.html

> Moreover, some rules designed to ease early transitions contributed to
>   later confusion. For example, the empty square brackets in the
>   function declaration
>
> int f(a) int a[]; { ... } are a living fossil, a remnant of NB's way
>   of declaring a pointer; a is, in this special case only, interpreted
>   in C as a pointer. The notation survived in part for the sake of
>   compatibility, in part under the rationalization that it would allow
>   programmers to communicate to their readers an intent to pass f a
>   pointer generated from an array, rather than a reference to a single
>   integer. Unfortunately, it serves as much to confuse the learner as to
>   alert the reader.

(Note: Chist.html uses a K&R style function definition. A prototyped equivalent of the above function definition would be `int f( int a[]){ ... }`.)

In short, the rule exists mainly to ease transition from B to C and to allow the programmer to signal to the reader that a pointer to the first element of an array is expected, rather than just a pointer to a single element (and do so without having to use a comment).

Function-typed parameters are also adjusted to pointers in a similar way.

```
void takeFuncPtr(void Func(void));
void takeFuncPtr(void (*Func)(void)); //compatible declaration
```

A perhaps more deeper question would be "why do arrays decay to pointers at all in C"?. The linked document provides an answer to that question as well:

> ...
>   These semantics represented an easy transition from B, and I
>   experimented with them for some months. Problems became evident when I
>   tried to extend the type notation, especially to add structured
>   (record) types. Structures, it seemed, should map in an intuitive way
>   onto memory in the machine, but in a structure containing an array,
>   there was no good place to stash the pointer containing the base of
>   the array, nor any convenient way to arrange that it be initialized.
>   For example, the directory entries of early Unix systems might be
>   described in C as
>
> struct {  int inumber;    char    name[14]; };
>
> I wanted the structure not
>   merely to characterize an abstract object but also to describe a
>   collection of bits that might be read from a directory. Where could
>   the compiler hide the pointer to name that the semantics demanded?
>   Even if structures were thought of more abstractly, and the space for
>   pointers could be hidden somehow, how could I handle the technical
>   problem of properly initializing these pointers when allocating a
>   complicated object, perhaps one that specified structures containing
>   arrays containing structures to arbitrary depth? The solution
>   constituted the crucial jump in the evolutionary chain between
>   typeless BCPL and typed C. It eliminated the materialization of the
>   pointer in storage, and instead caused the creation of the pointer
>   when the array name is mentioned in an expression. The rule, which
>   survives in today's C, is that values of array type are converted,
>   when they appear in expressions, into pointers to the first of the
>   objects making up the array.
>
> ...

Comment: Nice sleuthing!

Answer (score 0):

It is very hard to answer a Why question definitively.  In C, the array/pointer duality is used all over the place.  Once you get used to it, it won't seem confusing.

Don't think of it as a pointer to the first element -- think of it as the pointer to the whole array. `*a` is the first element, but `*(a+1)` is the next one.

Comment: Or, more canonically, `a[0]` and `a[1]`

Comment: If we are to think of it as the pointer to the whole array, then what should we think of `&a` (`a` is an array, not pointer)?

Comment: @LxerLx to be fair, `&arrayp` would be the same whether the signature was `int arrayp[]` or `int* arrayp`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I must admit that my brain was thinking in a different context in which `a` was an array whose definition (hence size information) is visible, not a function parameter which was decayed into a pointer. But again, now assuming `arrayp` is a function parameter declared as either `int arrayp[]` or `int *arrayp`, if we are to think of `arrayp` as _the pointer to the whole array_, then what should we think of `&arrayp` ?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Actually it is. But it is not consistent with the "concept" of `arrayp` being _pointer to the whole array_.